# Laravel csrf_token issue

Tags: laravel-4, csrf

I'm making web app using Laravel and AngularJS. To prevent CSRF, I added following script to index.php file.

```
<script>
angular.module("contactApp").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>');
</script>
```

But it shows the following Fatal error.

"Call to undefined function csrf_token()"

In Laravel setting, I changed the View Storage Paths in view.php to public_html folder. It seems it makes the error. How I can solve this problem with using an alternative View Storage Paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have a wrong value in you're view path?

```
// view.php
'paths' => array(__DIR__.'/../../public'),
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a CSRF token in Laravel the code is:

`<?php echo Form::token(); ?>`

or if your using Blade templates:

```
{{ Form::token() }}
```

Comment: End-user part is handled by AngularJS and Server part is handled by Laravel, so my challenge is how I can get the CSRF token in AngularJS and send it to Laravel when the end user submit the form. I'm not using the blade templates.